# prompt terminal to request ip addresses

Tags: perl, security, networking, cgi

Is there a way where i can make my perl script prompt me to enter a range of ip addresses when i run my perl script at the terminal?

I have a perl script that scans ip addresses through nmap.  I currently scan the ip addresses like so:

(`nmap -v -r xx.xx.xxx.xxx -p 1-25`);
(`nmap -v -r xx.xx.xxx.xxx -p 1-25`);

I would rather a command or function that where the terminal would prompt me to enter a range of ip address to scan, how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will print out `Input:` and wait for a user input line.  Read [here](http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perluserinput.php) for more information on user input.

```
print "Input: ";
my $input = <STDIN>;
```

Comment: Careful, **Tizag is not a good learning resource for Perl**. Its tutorials are of low quality, e.g. the page you linked to claims that `<STDIN> can be abbreviated by using simple <>`, but that's not true. `<>` is short for [`<ARGV>`](http://p3rl.org/var#ARGV), which happens to do the expected thing in the examples, but it really different than `<STDIN>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = <STDIN>; # read the next line
```

`STDIN` is standard input. See chapter **Input from Standard Input** in [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018452/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the OOTB nmap option to do this?
nmap has an option to read the IP address list from a file which you can read more about [here](http://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html) on the nmap website.

The specific option to look for is this:

> -iL  (Input from list)
>
> Reads target specifications from . Passing a huge list
>   of hosts is often awkward on the
>   command line, yet it is a common
>   desire. For example, your DHCP server
>   might export a list of 10,000 current
>   leases that you wish to scan. Or maybe
>   you want to scan all IP addresses
>   except for those to locate hosts using
>   unauthorized static IP addresses.
>   Simply generate the list of hosts to
>   scan and pass that filename to Nmap as
>   an argument to the -iL option. Entries
>   can be in any of the formats accepted
>   by Nmap on the command line (IP
>   address, hostname, CIDR, IPv6, or
>   octet ranges). Each entry must be
>   separated by one or more spaces, tabs,
>   or newlines. You can specify a hyphen
>   (-) as the filename if you want Nmap
>   to read hosts from standard input
>   rather than an actual file.
>
> The input file may contain comments that start with # and extend to the end of the line.